# Generate PDF and send mail

Tags: files

I have need to send pdf via drupal mail. I want to use tcpdf library but when im trying to use example i have error:
http: //..../tcpdf_example/download/simple

Fatal error: Call to a member function DrupalInitialize() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupalac_gw\sites\all\modules\tcpdf\tcpdf_example\tcpdf_example.pages.inc on line 55

```
  $html = theme('tcpdf_example_basic_html');

  // Never make an instance of TCPDF or TCPDFDrupal classes manually.
  // Use tcpdf_get_instance() instead.
  $tcpdf = tcpdf_get_instance();
  /* DrupalInitialize() is an extra method added to TCPDFDrupal that initializes
  *  some TCPDF variables (like font types), and makes possible to change the
  *  default header or footer without creating a new class.
  */
  $tcpdf->DrupalInitialize(array(
    'footer' => array(
      'html' => 'This is a test!! <em>Bottom of the page</em>',
    ),
    'header' => array(
      'callback' => array(
        'function' => 'tcpdf_example_default_header',
        // You can pass extra data to your callback.
        'context' => array(
          'welcome_message' => 'Hello, context array!',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ));
```

then somehow...

```
  ...
  $attachment = array(
  'filecontent' => $tcpdf->Output('', 'E');
  'filename' => 'test.txt',
  'filemime' => 'text/plain',
  );

  switch($key) {
  case 'notice':
  $langcode = $message['language']->language;
  $message['subject'] = 'example submission from' . $account;
  $message['body'][] =''. $account .' has submitted an example.';
  $message['params']['attachments'][] = $attachment;
  break;
  ...
```

What i need to correct to get rid of error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok First off all Installing drupal TCPDF module is not enough to have working pdf-s. We are also obligated to download TCPDF libray from http //www.tcpdf.org/ and place it to drupal files so that library will be avaible like this

> C:\xampp\htdocs\drupalac_gw\sites\all\libraries\tcpdf\tcpdf.php

above will solve:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function DrupalInitialize()

With working pdf library sending emails with attachments is easy i have like this:

```
drupal_mail('module', 'notice', "to@mail","", array(), "from@mail");
```

where:

```
function module_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  $attachment = array(
    'filecontent' => generatePdf("S"),
    'filename' => 'example-filename',
    'filemime' => 'application/pdf',
  );

  switch($key) {
    case 'notice':
      $langcode = $message['language']->language;
      $message['subject'] = 'example submission from ';
      $message['body'][] ='my example.';
      $message['params']['attachments'][] = $attachment;
      break;
  }  
}
```

And where:

```
function generatePdf($where="S") {
  $pdf = tcpdf_get_instance();

  $pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

  // set font
  $pdf->SetFont('freeserif', '', 12);

  $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 008', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

  // set header and footer fonts
  $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
  $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

  // set default monospaced font
  $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

  // set margins
  $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP+10, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
  $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
  $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

  // set auto page breaks
  $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

  // set image scale factor
  $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
  return $pdf->Output('example_008.pdf', $where);
}
```

Above is now my working example :)